# Como usar o DataFixtureLoader

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2, fixtures

Estou me baseando nesse [tutorial](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/alice-fixtures/fixtures), mas tenho as classes Country e State. Estou tentando importar os dados usando o comando:

```
php console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

quando executo ele **funciona para o CountryLoader**, carrega os dados e armazena no banco de dados, mas **dá falha ao tentar carregar StateLoader**.

A mensagem que ele exibe é:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Notice: Undefined index: country
```

Como fazer para funcionar o StateLoader?

CountryLoader.php

```
namespace Test\Bundle\TestBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Hautelook\AliceBundle\Alice\DataFixtureLoader;

/**
 * Description of CountryLoader
 *
 */
class CountryLoader extends DataFixtureLoader {

    protected function getFixtures() {
        return array(
            __DIR__ . '/country.yml',
        );
    }

}
```

StateLoader.php

```
namespace Test\Bundle\TestBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Hautelook\AliceBundle\Alice\DataFixtureLoader;

/**
 * Description of StateLoader
 *
 */
class StateLoader extends DataFixtureLoader {

    protected function getFixtures() {
        return array(
            __DIR__ . '/country.yml',
            __DIR__ . '/state.yml',
        );
    }

}
```

Country.php

```
/**
 * Description of Country
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="country")
 */
class Country {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, unique=true) 
    */
        private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8, unique=true) 
     */
    private $iso3;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8, unique=true) 
     */
    private $numcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8, unique=true) 
     */
    private $acronym;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="City", cascade={"all"}, mappedBy="country")
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $states;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getIso3() {
        return $this->iso3;
    }

    public function getNumcode() {
        return $this->numcode;
    }

    public function getAcronym() {
        return $this->acronym;
    }

    public function getStates() {
        return $this->states;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setIso3($iso3) {
        $this->iso3 = $iso3;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setNumcode($numcode) {
        $this->numcode = $numcode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setAcronym($acronym) {
        $this->acronym = $acronym;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setStates(ArrayCollection $states) {
        $this->states = $states;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

State.php

```
/**
 * Description of State
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="state")
 */
class State {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, unique=true) 
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8, unique=true) 
     */
    private $acronym;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="City", cascade={"all"}, mappedBy="state")
     * @var ArrayCollection 
     */
    private $cities;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="states", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_acronym", referencedColumnName="acronym", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @var Country
     */
    private $country;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAcronym() {
        return $this->acronym;
    }

    public function getCities() {
        return $this->cities;
    }

    public function getCountry() {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setAcronym($acronym) {
        $this->acronym = $acronym;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCities(ArrayCollection $cities) {
        $this->cities = $cities;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCountry(Country $country) {
        $this->country = $country;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

country.yml

```
Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\Country:
    BR: 
        iso3: BRA
        acronym: BR
        numcode: 76
        name: Brasil
```

state.yml

```
Test\Bundle\TestBundle\Entity\State:
    AC:
        acronym: AC
        name: Acre
        country: @BR
```

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar direitinho, com o seu próprio exemplo. Havia só alguns problemas no mapeamento das entidades (que verifiquei com o comando `doctrine:schema:validate`) e, além disso, retirei o `country.yml` do carregamento dos estados (senão carregaria os dados em duplicata).

Comment: Não tinha usando o doctrine:schema:validate, haviam vários erros nas minha entidades. Agora está exibindo apenas:

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'SBCorp2B\Bundle\SystemBundle\Entity\State' mapping is invalid:
* The referenced column name 'acronym' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'SBCorp2B\Bundle\SystemBundle\Entity\Country'.
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'SBCorp2B\Bundle\SystemBundle\Entity\City' mapping is invalid:
* The referenced column name 'acronym' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'SBCorp2B\Bundle\SystemBundle\Entity\State'.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti removi as anotações do @ORM\JoinColumn, após verificar os erros com o doctrine:schema:validate e corrigir, gravou, mas nesse caso perdi o a exclusão em Cascata, não tenho mais erro no doctrine:schema:validate

Comment: Acho que a exclusão em cascata pode ser mantida. O problema seria mesmo definir o acrônimo do país como chave estrangeira da tabela de estados, acho que o Doctrine não lida bem com isso (além de não ser uma prática recomendada).

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Excelente, já resolveu o problema, coloquei o JoinCollumn pelo id mesmo e mantive o onDelete,sua dica de usar o doctrine:schema:validate foi espetacular, não tinha o habito de usar. Agora como fazemos com esse post? O erro foi falta de atenção mesmo no mapeamento e falta de conhecimento sobre chave estrangeira no doctrine. Vai postar uma reposta ou como faremos com esse post? fechamos?

Comment: Vou escrever uma resposta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem alguns erros com sua modelagem de dados e acredito que o carregamento das *fixtures* possa estar de alguma forma relacionada a isso:

1. A chave estrangeira da tabela `country` na tabela `state` é o acrônimo do país ao invés do `id`; essa não é uma prática muito recomendada – deve-se usar o `id` da tabela.
2. As fixtures dos países (`country.yml`) está sendo carregada duas vezes: no carregamento de países e no carregamento de estados. Não é necessário criar uma classe para cada arquivo. Pode-se criar uma única classe (por exemplo, `loadLocationData`) e carregar todos os dados inerentes a aquele domínio.

Além disso, repliquei seu modelo aqui e vi que há alguns problemas no mapeamento da classes com as tabelas no banco de dados. Quando você modelar uma base de dados usando o Doctrine, procure usar sempre o comando `doctrine:schema:validate` para ver se não há nenhum problema no mapeamento. :)